# mongo save save more than 1 records at ones

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-scala

I want to save more than 1 records at one time that means save block of records.
 Is it possible in mongoDB. if yes plz some one tell.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible but for specifics you have tell us which language/driver you are using.

Comment: sorry didn't read all your tags, can't seem to find a bulk insert command for scala either, the c# and c++ driver do support it.

Answer (score 0):

The java driver's [`DBCollection`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html) supports [`insert`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#insert%28java.util.List%29) with a `List<DBObject>` parameter this should be usable from scala as well.

**Edit**

[Cabash](http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/current/) also supports a similar [`insert`](http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/2.1.5.0/scaladoc/#com.mongodb.casbah.MongoCollection) method that should do the trick.